# Android Maven Plugin - dex creation with too long command line (windows)

Tags: java, android, windows, maven, dex

I have a big problem with my android project: If I want to build my project on windows command line (cmd.exe) I get an error with the message: `command line too long` from the dex call.

The problem is that a lot of dependencies are defined and needed for this project, so the command line is longer than 3000 characters.

I searched for  a way to make the dex build step of android maven plugin convert each jar in a single process step instead of converting all jars in one process step. Is it be able to do this?